# Pass one variable to next in JSON object in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to be able to access user data in comments.

```
  def index
    @user = User.all

    @libraries = Library.all.order('created_at ASC')
    @comments = Comment.all
    @user_likes = UserLike.all
    render :json => @libraries, :include => [:user, :comments, :user_likes]
  end
```

I tried this:

```
render :json => @libraries, :include => [:user, {:comments => :user}, :user_likes]
```

And it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think we need to know (1) how your models relate to each other, (2) what you're trying to render, (3) what you expect as output, and (4) what actual output you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the associations set up, you need to add `include` for the nested associations:

```
   render :json => @libraries, 
    :include => {:user, {:comments => { include: :user}}, :user_likes}
```

When rendering JSON like this, Rails calls `as_json` first to convert the payload to hash. That's when the option `include` is used. You can check the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) to see how it works.